Why is a coefficient in front of $Y_{t-1}$ in a random walk (equal to 1) not an autocorrelation coefficient?
As it is said everywhere autocorrelation measures the correlation between a time series variable and its lagged values at different time intervals. Then why can't we say that coefficient in front of $Y_{t-1}$ in a random walk is an autocorrelation coefficient if it exactly does show how previous lagged value is related to a current one. What's the difference between autocorrelation coefficient and this one then?

Hint: what is the formula for the slope in a univariate regression?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Yule%E2%80%93Walker_equations

Please tell us how to make sense of "autocorrelation" in a non-stationary time series!
